# What's the name of my wart?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I once had a wart, so I got it removed.
> It weighed like a kilo; I felt so improved!
>
> I said, "Can I keep it?" The doc said, "Please have!"
> It sits in a jar on my desk, named "---- ---."

(The answer will be two words.)

Hint:

> Maybe this question should be migrated to [META.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is certainly opinion-based and very much a case of "Can you guess what I'm thinking." As such (like the wart), this riddle should be flagged, reviewed by respected members of the community, voted on and promptly closed and/or removed.

Comment: I'm going to assume your recommendation that the puzzle be closed and/or removed is not sincere; perhaps it's a subtle hint somehow. Anyway, do the dashes indicate the lengths of those two words (4,3) or should we not interpret them that way?

Comment: Yes: four letters, then three; rhyme and meter are hints, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess I'll go with

> [Left nav](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369107/7682922).

Answer (score 0):

The missing words are

> left nav

referring to [the latest cancerous deformity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/300663)

> [on the Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/300663), inflicted on defenseless users
> by the [Developer Affinity and Growth team](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351751)

although I don’t know why you would want to retain even a reminder of it.